# Open MP integration with BDD [Binary Decision Diagrams]

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, garbage-collection, openmp

I am currently new to openMP and Buddy 2.4, I have been working on a problem to create parallel BDD's with open MP architecture, when I make parallel BDD's with the following code

```
    /* open MP code  */
     #pragma omp parallel for shared(z) private(tid) num_threads(4)
     for(tid=0;tid<32;tid++)
       {
           int ti = omp_get_thread_num();        
           z[tid]=z[tid]&z[64-tid-1];
           printf("\n z[%d] = z[%d] & z[%d] from thread number : %d, %d \n", tid,tid, 64-tid-1,ti,bdd_nodecount(z[tid]));
}
```

actually I am anding first 64 bdd's and storing them in first 32 BDD's

and nodecount for first 64 BDD's before anding

```
Node count for z[0] = 0 

Node count for z[1] = 0 

Node count for z[2] = 0 

Node count for z[3] = 0 

Node count for z[4] = 0 

Node count for z[5] = 0 

Node count for z[6] = 0 

Node count for z[7] = 0 

Node count for z[8] = 0 

Node count for z[9] = 0 

Node count for z[10] = 0 

Node count for z[11] = 0 

Node count for z[12] = 0 

Node count for z[13] = 1 

Node count for z[14] = 1 

Node count for z[15] = 1 

Node count for z[16] = 1 

Node count for z[17] = 1 

Node count for z[18] = 1 

Node count for z[19] = 3 

Node count for z[20] = 5 

Node count for z[21] = 5 

Node count for z[22] = 5 

Node count for z[23] = 5 

Node count for z[24] = 5 

Node count for z[25] = 3 

Node count for z[26] = 3 

Node count for z[27] = 3 

Node count for z[28] = 5 

Node count for z[29] = 5 

Node count for z[30] = 5 

Node count for z[31] = 5 

Node count for z[32] = 7 

Node count for z[33] = 5 

Node count for z[34] = 5 

Node count for z[35] = 5 

Node count for z[36] = 7 

Node count for z[37] = 7 

Node count for z[38] = 7 

Node count for z[39] = 7 

Node count for z[40] = 9 

Node count for z[41] = 7 

Node count for z[42] = 7 

Node count for z[43] = 7 

Node count for z[44] = 7 

Node count for z[45] = 7 

Node count for z[46] = 9 

Node count for z[47] = 11 

Node count for z[48] = 13 

Node count for z[49] = 13 

Node count for z[50] = 13 

Node count for z[51] = 15 

Node count for z[52] = 15 

Node count for z[53] = 9 

Node count for z[54] = 11 

Node count for z[55] = 11 

Node count for z[56] = 11 

Node count for z[57] = 11 

Node count for z[58] = 15 

Node count for z[59] = 15 

Node count for z[60] = 15 

Node count for z[61] = 19 

Node count for z[62] = 23 

Node count for z[63] = 19
```

the problem is that the code is running perfectly serially (no openMP used), but while using openMP, garbage collection is being initiated because of which the nodes are being deleted.

```
Garbage collection #2: 10000019 nodes / 10000017 free / 1.3s / 2.1s total
BDD error: Unknown BDD - was not in node table
BDD error: Unknown BDD - was not in node table
BDD error: Unknown BDD - was not in node table
BDD error: Unknown BDD - was not in node table
```

I am unable to understand why this is happening, here are the possible solution [Not working] I have come up with

**Solution 1 [Not working]**

Provide possible reference and deference to the nodes. 
This part of solution isn't working, because we have to convert bdd to BDD and bddithvar(i) [which I am using in some part of code] is not able to convert to BDD so error conversion error is coming.

**Solution 2 [Not working]**

Use sections to run the program on Open MP

This part is also not working, throwing same error.

**Solution 3 [Not working]**

Divide the BDD into two or more parts and transfer some part of content to another BDD, for example creating 2 BDD (z1[32] and z[64]) , transfer half of the z[64] to z1[32] and run the code parallely. But still throwing the same error.

**Solution 4 [still trying]**

Initiate a garbage collection stop specifically by debugging the code
Still figuring out how to do this, any comments regarding this would help.

**Solution 5 [Not working]**

Possible give a particular thread a particular task.
For example thread 1 should do anding of 10 BDD's and thread 2 should do anding of next BDD's and so on, but still not working throwing same error.

My program is basically anding of BDD's and there are 6 loops
First anding of 64 BDD's then 32, then 16 and so on..

So if by chance clears off the first 64 BDD's anding, it always get stuck between the 32 BDD's anding, it doesn't get past it.

So my question is : why is the garbage collection occuring, although the 64 BDD contains some node value, why is garbage collection occuring, is there any way that garbage collection should be stopped, any comments regarding this would be appreciated, thanks

EDIT : This program is running perfectly serially, but giving garbage collection parallely

Comment: You appear to be writing C code. Neither C nor OpenMP include garbage collection, so the GC messages must be coming from your bdd library. Is it possible that the bdd library isn't thread-safe? Is it possible that z isn't initialized?

Comment: ohh, I forgot to add, this program is running perfectly serially, but giving garbage collection using open mp